# Limit 255 char in recipients fields. Oracle Webcenter Portal

Tags: oracle, email, outlook, webcenter

I Oracle Webcenter Portal configure to opertate with my local Outlook mail client.
If I want sent a mail to all participants of a portal I have a limit of 255 char into recipients field.
How can I get over this problem?

Comment: I am only aware of the limit on the number of recepients, but I am not aware of size limit. Did you try CLOB? But, as I said, number of recipients would again be a restriction.

Answer (score 0):

For certain versions of WebCenter Portal there is a known issue with the mailto protocol and a 256 character limi.
This is a known product limitation. See the following Oracle Support note for a workaround:

Problem with character limitation of the 'mailto' protocol in WebCenter Spaces (Doc ID 1149020.1)

Comment: I can't find the note... I try search it on Oracle Forum https://community.oracle.com/welcome

Comment: This is an Oracle Support note, you can find it on My Oracle Support through http://support.oracle.com